# How to rotate images in Caffe on-the-fly for training set augmentation?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I know that there is a "mirror" parameter in the default data layer, but is there a way to do arbitrary rotations (really, I would just like to do multiples of 90 degrees), preferably in Python?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Python Layer to do the same. The usage of a Python Layer is demonstrated in `caffe_master/examples/py_caffe/`. Here you could make use of a python script as the input layer to your network. You could describe the behavior of rotations in this layer.